# Layer not loading into ArcGIS Pro Catalog window

Tags: arcgis-pro, metadata, feature-layer, catalog-window

Using ArcGIS Pro 2.7, Learn ArcGIS trial license

I imported a feature class vector layer created in ArcMap into ArcGIS Pro. Under layer properties, I was able to copy the data sources metadata to the layer and access the metadata description in the Catalog window. I did this by navigating to the project map in the Catalog window, and clicking on the layer name listed on the left side of the window.

As part of an existing project in ArcGIS Pro, I re-projected the vector layer as a new feature class in the map project, however the new layer is not appearing in the layer list in the Catalog view. At the bottom of the Catalog view the status is Loading..., apparently unable to upload the new layer into the Catalog view even though the new layer exists in the contents pane of the map project.

Comment: By “Catalog window” do you mean the Catalog pane?

Comment: I was referring to the Catalog view, and edited the question, and turns out it was simply hitting the refresh button

Answer (score 1):

I had to refresh the Catalog, and that was why it wasn't appearing in the Catalog view